# Python convert string of dictionary to dataframe

Tags: pandas, string, python-3.8

I have a large string which has data in the following format:

```
str = '{"Item":"0","ADDRESS_ON_URL":"702-hartman-st-houston-tx-77007"},{"Item":"1","ADDRESS_ON_URL":"818-reinicke-st-houston-tx-77007"}'
```

I am looking to create a dataframe of the above data with desired output as following:

```
Item    ADDRESS_ON_URL
 0      702-hartman-st-houston-tx-77007
 1      818-reinicke-st-houston-tx-77007
```

I am not even sure how to approach the above.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.read_json()` with `lines=True`:

```py
s = '{"Item":"0","ADDRESS_ON_URL":"702-hartman-st-houston-tx-77007"},{"Item":"1","ADDRESS_ON_URL":"818-reinicke-st-houston-tx-77007"}'

df = pd.read_json(s, lines=True)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Item                    ADDRESS_ON_URL
0     0   702-hartman-st-houston-tx-77007
1     1  818-reinicke-st-houston-tx-77007
```

Comment: lines = True .. was the important trick here :) first I tried just read_json and it wasn't working